# Skeleton css columns overlap

Tags: html, css, skeleton-css-boilerplate

I'm trying to place two images beside a form and make it responsive using skeleton css:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="five columns">
            <form id="sign-up-form">
                <div class="row">
                    <label for="signUpUsernameInput">Username</label>
                    <div class="input-wrapper">
                        <img src="/images/icons/user.png">
                        <input type="text" name="username" class="u-full-width" id="signUpUsernameInput">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <label for="signUpEmailInput">Email</label>
                    <div class="input-wrapper">
                        <img src="/images/icons/mail.png">
                        <input type="text" name="email" class="u-full-width" id="signUpEmailInput">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <label for="signUpPasswordInput">Password</label>
                    <div class="input-wrapper">
                        <img src="/images/icons/password.png">
                        <input type="password" name="password" class="u-full-width" id="signUpPasswordInput">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <label id="agree-terms">
                    <div class="row">
                        <input type="checkbox">
                        <span class="label-body">I agree to the <a href="#">Terms of Service</a> and <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></span>
                    </div>
                </label>
                <div class="row">
                    <button id="sign-up-button-green-large" class="u-full-width">Sign Up</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="seven columns">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="six columns">
                    <img src="/images/box.png">
                </div>
                <div class="six columns">
                    <img src="/images/box.png">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is what it looks like on a normal desktop 100% zoom:
[image]

And then when I shrink it at a certain point the boxes overlap:
[image]

The boxes also get pushed outside the div:
[image]

And eventually they collapse normally:
[image]
JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/473vac9x/2/

How do I make the boxes not overlap and get pushed outside the div when I resize the browser? Thanks so much!

Comment: @S.Serp Sure, https://jsfiddle.net/473vac9x/2/ (boxes are orange)

Comment: what should be done when the orange images are bigger than their parent width? should images be scaled/cropped or hide? Also could we use a background instead of img tag?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this in one of two ways.

You can either add the class: "u-max-full-width" to the images like this:

```
<img class="u-max-full-width" src="path/to/image/here" />
```

Or you can define image max-with in the stylesheet like so:

```
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```